# Qlik - Require JS Module Dependency with ChartJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs, qliksense

I want to load Javascript plugins for chartJS within QLIK Sense Developer.

I have set up the define as below.

```
define( [
   'jquery',
   './PropertiesPannel',

   '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.js',
   '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.min.js',
   //'./chartjs-plugin-zoom',
   './chartjs-plugin-annontation',
   //'./chartjs-plugin-datalabels',
   'qlik'
],
function ( $, ProperitesPannel, Chart,Hammer,ChartAnnotation,qlik) { foo,baa}
```

- Problem 1: ON Qlik App run time, 'Chart' is undefined error is
  happening for the data labels plugin.
- Problem 2: ON Qlik App run time,
  on occasion, the Zoom and annotations plug error as Problem 1

I believe the problem is because the packages are not loading in order so the plugins are loading before main chartJS plugin thus making `Chart` not globally ready to be used.

How can I load these in a way that will make sure on run time, everything is loaded correctly?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I load these in a way that will make sure on run time, everything is loaded correctly?

This option is called `shim`. Here quick example:

```js
requirejs.config({
  shim: {
    '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.js': ['jquery'],
  }
});
```

In this example I am telling Require to load `jQuery` before loading `Chart.bundle.js` because it needs it. For all files which does not AMD support you have to set that.

You can learn more in the official page:
https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim

Comment: So I have given this a go and things still seem to not be working. I have used this idea above to go like this.

Chart js Requires Hammerjs
Plugin 1 requires chartjs 
plugin 2 requires chartjs

This is now throwing more errors than before.

I think this could also be something to do with how the plugins are set to export the code as they differ across all 3.